# How do I keep the values of a child function in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, getter-setter

I am trying to solve a problem about inheritance. It is about making a base account and then make a debit card that inherits from the base account.

The problem is that I do not know how to keep the value of the method in the child class.

Here is my code:

```
public class BaseAccount {

private double opening;

private double currentAmount = 0.0;

private double amount;


public BaseAccount(double opening, double currentAmount, double amount) {

this.opening = opening;

this.currentAmount = currentAmount;

this.amount = amount;

}


public double getOpening() {

return opening;

}


public void setOpening(double opening) {

this.opening = opening;

}


public double getCurrentAmount() {

return currentAmount;

}


public void setCurrentAmount(double currentAmount) {

this.currentAmount = currentAmount;

}


public double getAmount() {

return amount;

}


public void setAmount(double amount) {

this.amount = amount;

}

public String opening(double opening) {

this.opening = opening;

this.currentAmount = currentAmount + opening;

return "This account has been openend with " + this.opening;

}

public String deposit(double amount) {

this.currentAmount += amount;

return "Depositing " + amount;

}

public String balance() {

return "Balance: " + currentAmount;

}

}



public class DebitCard extends BaseAccount{


public DebitCard(double opening, double currentAmount, double amount) {

super(opening, currentAmount, amount);

}

public String withdraw(double amount) {

double currentAmount = getCurrentAmount() - amount;

return amount + " have been retired. \nBalance: " + currentAmount;

}

}



public class Inheritance {


public static void main(String[] args) {

BaseAccount base1 = new BaseAccount(0,0,0);

System.out.println(base1.opening(500));

System.out.println(base1.deposit(22.22));

System.out.println(base1.balance());

DebitCard debit1 = new DebitCard(0,0,0);

System.out.println(debit1.opening(400));

System.out.println(debit1.deposit(33.33));

System.out.println(debit1.balance());

System.out.println(debit1.withdraw(33.33));

System.out.println(debit1.balance());

}

}
```

Run:

```
This account has been opened with 500.0

Depositing 22.22

Balance: 522.22

This account has been opened with 400.0

Depositing 33.33

Balance: 433.33

33.33 have been retired.

Balance: 400.0

Balance: 433.33
```

I do not understand why the balance at the ends ignores the change I made in the retire function of the child class. I know I have to do something with the getters and setters but I do not know what exactly.

Comment: Looks like you need to call `super.withdraw`.

Comment: I don't think there is a `withdraw` method in the super class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double currentAmount = getCurrentAmount() - amount;`

This statement does not change the value of the `currentAmount` field: it creates a new `currnetAmount` local variable. If you want to be able to modify the `currentAmount` field then it cannot be private.

Try adding `setCurrentAmount(currentAmount);` to the withdraw method.

Also, the `amount` field is unused.

Edit:

```
public String withdraw(double amount) {

   double currentAmount = getCurrentAmount() - amount;

   setCurrentAmount(currentAmount);

   return amount + " have been retired. \nBalance: " + currentAmount;

}
```

Comment: How do I add the setter? Can you write the code of that part? That is what I have been trying to do, but I do not get it until I see it in code.

Comment: You already have the setter method written. Just use it to set the value of `currentAmount` in your `withdraw` method.